# How do i create a return button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a return button in python using tkinter.

In one file, I have a mainscreen that contains buttons that lead me to other windows from other files via importing them. I want to make a return button in this new window that will take me back to the original window but nothing is working.

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: "take me back to the original window" is a bit vague. Are you destroying and recreating windows? Creating multiple Toplevel windows? Have a single window where you're swapping frames in and out? Please provide a [mcve] that has a couple of windows that you are switching to so that we can see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

When I create Back buttons inside Tkinter menus - I normally create the menu's inside a frame. then you can unpack the frame and pack another one in. this allows you to create easily changeable menu's. Please share your code next time so we can give a more detailed response.